# Can I add insulation to the top of my oven range (under the drip pans)

Tags: range

The surface (top) of my 1982 Kenmore continuous cleaning oven gets very hot while baking; hot enough to melt plastic bags, etc.

Can I add a layer of oven wrap insulation to the top of the oven, under the lid?

The drawback will be that the insulation will get dirty from drippings, etc that drop down from above.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with a sheet of aluminum on top of it to prevent drippings from saturating the insulation (which would cause a fire hazard)  However, you could cause the top steel of the oven to overheat and damage the finish.  And if a fire started and burned the house down if they discover the oven was modified your homeowners insurance may not pay out.  There are all kinds of liability risks to modifying a power appliance.  Since this is a cheap electric oven you can get a much better one for not much money used off craigslist.

However, we have a pretty expensive range ourselves my wife has melted plastic by accident on top of it.  I just handed her a razor blade scraper and told her plastic and cooking do not mix.  It only happened once. :-)

Comment: Make that two layers.  The top one sacrificial and gets changed when it gets dirty.
All of the insulation material should be hi-temp, so fiberglass i your best bet.

Comment: Great idea, thank you!